# Getting keys and values from zabbix API response list Python3

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, zabbix

I have a problem with works with data from zabbix. I create a request like below:

```
requests = zapi.host.get({"output": ZabbixApiValues,"selectInventory":ZabbixApiValues, "filter": {"host": ["Cisco"]}})
```

ZabbixApiValues is a list of fields which I need to get from zabbix: (list is make in other function which doesn't matter right now)

```
['oob_ip', 'location', 'description', 'host', 'os']
<class 'list'>
```

then from Zabbix API I get response:

```
[{'hostid': '10460', 'description': 'This is testing host', 'host': 'Cisco', 'inventory': {'hostid': '10460', 'oob_ip': '', 'location': 'Tokyo', 'os': 'Linux Mint'}}]
<class 'list'>
```

and now I have to get all of those fields

```
('host': 'Cisco', 'location': 'Tokyo' etc. etc.)
```

from zabbix response and create API requests to another system in XML format.
I know what to do this but I can't get necessary fields from this response. I expect I get only [key]:[value] without json children exactly:
`'hostid': '10460', 'description': 'This is testing host', 'host': 'Cisco','hostid': '10460', 'oob_ip': '', 'location': 'Tokyo', 'os': 'Linux Mint'`
maybe as dictionary. without "inventory". Then I could get keys and values and create xml.

Now I can get string with all of data or x['inventory'] with only inventory data instead of all of fields.

Please help

Comment: can't you access fields like x[0]['host'] ?

Comment: print(x[0]['description'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Zabbix API response, is list or str ? the list you have posted will not give error if you will try to access element like that. you should check the response whether it is "[]" or []

Comment: print (type(requests))
<class 'list'>

Comment: can show the output of requests[0] ?

Comment: In addition raw Zabbix response (in my case is variable "requests" i get list which is not readable by json viewer. . . so i do JSrequests = json.dumps(requests) and now is it string type and OK for json format

Comment: response is above in description of my problem, (after the header "then from Zabbix API I get response") [{'hostid': '10460'..........

Comment: do, x = json.loads(JSrequests) then x[0]['description']

Comment: ok, I know this, but problem is what collect keys with values because i have to send this by API xml. and second case is how to search list in response, not string values. ZabbixApiValues it depends on host so this list could be diferent.

Comment: requests[0][Zabbix Values] instead of requests[0]['description'] and I have to match host to name of host, description to description, not key:host to values:description.

Comment: resp_dict = x[0]  doesn't it a dict what you were asking ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zabbix response is of type list  and then you are converting it to json data so now it's json string you can't access elements like that, you need to load the json data like

```
JSrequests = json.dumps(requests)
x = json.loads(JSrequests)
resp_dict = x[0]
```

now this is a dict, you can access elements like

```
x[0]['description']
```

not sure why you are doing this, requests is of type list, no need to convert to json, get the dict out of list and access elements i.e

```
x = requests[0] # dict
```

Answer (score 0):

print (requests[0])

```
{'hostid': '10460', 'description': 'This is testing host names Fortigate 100D.', 'host': 'Fortinet-Fortigate 100D', 'inventory': {'hostid': '10460', 'oob_ip': '', 'location': 'Warsaw', 'os': ''}}
```

print (requests)

```
[{'hostid': '10460', 'description': 'This is testing host names Fortigate 100D.', 'host': 'Fortinet-Fortigate 100D', 'inventory': {'hostid': '10460', 'oob_ip': '', 'location': 'Warsaw', 'os': ''}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple... I am new in Python and... ugh
thank's. So i have:

```
print('requests',requests)
print ('ZabbixApiValues',ZabbixApiValues)
for x in ZabbixApiValues:
    if (x in requests[0]):
        print(x,":",requests[0][x])
    elif (x in requests[0]['inventory']):
        print(x,":",requests[0]['inventory'][x])
```

and i get:

```
requests [{'hostid': '10460', 'description': 'This is testing host names Fortigate 100D.', 'host': 'Fortinet-Fortigate 100D', 'inventory': {'hostid': '10460', 'oob_ip': '', 'location': 'Warsaw', 'os': ''}}]
ZabbixApiValues ['oob_ip', 'location', 'description', 'host', 'os']
oob_ip : 
location : Warsaw
description : This is testing host names Fortigate 100D.
host : Fortinet-Fortigate 100D
os :
```